# Programming Android with NDK -

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm developing a library in C++ for android. I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 and I downloaded NDK R10e. In Project Structure I set the path to ndk and also set in PATH environment variable.
I created a jni folder under app->src->main and added a simple file .c
In file .c I include  header.
After build the project with success, apparently, when the app is executed on device the app stop with critical error. In logcat I can see:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: example.testjni, PID: 10923
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/example.testjni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/example.testjni-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libhello-jni.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
        at evanescentwave.testjni.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:21)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
```

After googoling for hours, can someone give me an idea? Why in android studio NDK is deprecated and I have to set `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in gradle.properties?

Thank you!
Roberto

Answer (score 1):

Your final "Why" has an easy answer: a new NDK-friendly gradle [plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) is under (hopefully, final stages of) development.

As to what caused the UnsatisfiedLinkError: make sure that your ndk module is named "hello-jni" and check if the APK you build contains the library for a compatible ABI (compatible with your device).

Comment: Thank you.
After further investigation, in gradle console I can see:

Comment: Re: `Native C/C++ source code is found, but it seems that NDK option is not configured`: please check that **local.properties** file contains the correct path for **ndk.dir**. If you are on Windows, this may look like `ndk.dir=C\:\\Android\\ndk`. On any system, avoid path with spaces. See more at http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration

Comment: Further checking, do you have `android { ndk { moduleName "hello-jni" } }` in your **build.gradle**?